# Computer is slow, fan is loud

Tags: 16.04

A couple of hours after reboot, everything starts to get really slow. I notice that when this happens the cpu fan starts to make loud sound, but the cpu is not heavily utilized. The cpu temperature is not so high (around 60C)

I'm using intel integrated graphics. I actually have nvidia card, but couldn't configure it yet, so it's not being used

Answer (score 0):

Did you look which program was using so much CPU? 
You can use some text based software like top, ps or htop to see it.

I am suspecting tracker-miner to cause that, as it happened to many people with Ubuntu.